# ¿Cómo enviar valor de un SelectField por medio de un javascript SetInterval a Flask?

Tags: javascript, select, flask, setinterval

Esta es la finalidad: una web para una que mis estudiantes tomen unas pruebas, y enviar las respuestas ya sea por medio del un botón submit, o si el tiempo no les alcanza, enviar automáticamente por medio del setInterval con un script de js.

```
<body>
    <audio autoplay="autoplay" src={{audio}}></audio>
    <form method="POST">
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div class="item1">
                <figure class=”gallery__item">
                    <img src={{img}} class="gallery__img" alt="Image 1">
                </figure>
            </div>
            <div class="item3">AUDIO 1</div>
            <div class="item4">AUDIO 2</div>
            <div class="item5">AUDIO 3</div>
            <div class="item6">AUDIO 4</div>
            <div class="item7">AUDIO 5</div>
            <div class="item8">
                <select name="answer1">
                    <option value="none">---</option>
                    <option value="audio1">audio 1</option>
                    <option value="audio2">audio 2</option>
                    <option value="audio3">audio 3</option>
                    <option value="audio4">audio 4</option>
                    <option value="audio5">audio 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item9">
                <select name="answer2">
                    <option value="none">---</option>
                    <option value="audio1">audio 1</option>
                    <option value="audio2">audio 2</option>
                    <option value="audio3">audio 3</option>
                    <option value="audio4">audio 4</option>
                    <option value="audio5">audio 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item10">
                <select name="answer3">
                    <option value="none">---</option>
                    <option value="audio1">audio 1</option>
                    <option value="audio2">audio 2</option>
                    <option value="audio3">audio 3</option>
                    <option value="audio4">audio 4</option>
                    <option value="audio5">audio 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item11">
                <select name="answer3">
                    <option value="none">---</option>
                    <option value="audio1">audio 1</option>
                    <option value="audio2">audio 2</option>
                    <option value="audio3">audio 3</option>
                    <option value="audio4">audio 4</option>
                    <option value="audio5">audio 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item12">
                <select name="answer5">
                    <option value="none">---</option>
                    <option value="audio1">audio 1</option>
                    <option value="audio2">audio 2</option>
                    <option value="audio3">audio 3</option>
                    <option value="audio4">audio 4</option>
                    <option value="audio5">audio 5</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="item13">
                <form method=post enctype=multipart/form-data>
                    <input type=submit value=Siguiente>
                    <script>


                        var count={{time}};
                        var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second
                        function timer()
                        {
                          count=count-1;
                          if (count <= 0)
                          {
                             clearInterval(counter);
                             window.location.href = '{{redirect_url}}';
                             return
                          }
                          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML=count + " secs";
                        }
                    </script>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="item2">
                <h6><span id="timer"></span></h6>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Hasta ahora logro que el botón submit envíe el dato y vaya a la siguiente url, pero cuando el cambio de url se da por medio de el script, no logro que el dato sea cargado por el código en flask.

Seguro la respuesta es una simpleza, pero es mi primer proyecto usando flask, html y JS

Comment: En vez de una redirección con `window.location.href = '{{redirect_url}}';` deberías enviar el formulario. Edita la pregunta para agregar el código completo, porque ahora en ese formulario solo tienes el botón y la pregunta (o respuestas) fuera.

Comment: Ya he agregado el código completo. Ahí puede ver el formulario que contiene las preguntas y respuestas

Comment: Pero con la respuesta de @Triby todo tuvo sentido, solo agregar un id al formulario y cambiar la redirreción por `document.getElementById("form_id").submit();`